# SSRS report to be hidden on screen, but data to be shown on export option

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I've got a SSRS report with many columns. Showing this report on screen can be tedious to use. I would like to hide this report on screen, but data should be visible when user choses to export via export option on SSRS. On hiding this report, through Tablix properties, it was not visible, but on exporting to CSV/PDF, data was not visible there also. What should be done to show data on export??

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you want to hide report items based on how they're rendered. Use an expression like the following for visibility of your report items:

```
=Iif(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL", True, False)
```

Alternatively, if you're using the ReportViewer component currently, I'd suggest replacing it with a regular control in your application framework, and sending a Stream of data with a rendered report (rendered from the SSRS web service).